# Vue.js - Implement previous/next buttons to display surveys questions

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have this code in my Vue.js component. It will display some survey questions to the user on a mobile app.

```html
      <div class="col-12 p-0" v-for="( i, index ) in questions" :key="i">
        <p class="lead fw-bold">{{ item.question }}</p>
        <div class="form-check" v-for="(choice, index) in item.choices" :key="index">
          <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" :name="i" :value="index" @change="checkAnswer(item.questionIndex, index)" :disabled="answeredQuestions[i]">
          <label class="form-check-label" for="">{{ index }}) {{ choice }}</label>
        </div>
      </div>
```

```js
export default {
  name: 'Quiz',
  data() {
    return {
      answeredQuestions: []
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    front.on('questions', (data) => { 
      console.log(data) 
      this.$store.commit('quizQuestions', data);
      this.$store.commit('contentLoaded', true);
    });
  },
  computed: {
    isLoading() {
      return this.$store.getters.showLoader;
    },
    questions() {
      return this.$store.getters.quiz;
    },
  },
  methods: {
    checkAnswer(questionIndex, choice) {
      this.answeredQuestions.push(true);
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

Since I want to avoid the scroll, I want to implement a button that when is clicked will display the next question to the user. Since I'm using a `v-for` I'm not sure on how to implement this, as I know `v-if` and `v-for` will conflict if used together. How can I proceed?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Swiper](https://github.surmon.me/vue-awesome-swiper/?ref=madewithvuejs.com) with buttons for that. Or if you want to connect each question with route you can change current route on every question - you just need to pass the handler to your buttons with `$route.push('surveyId/questionId')` calls. Each option will help you avoid using v-if with v-for.

Comment: I'm not sure if swiper can be a good solution, I don't need to create a slider with images and my vue app will be packed as an apk for mobile so the ux will not be very suitable with a slider. At the moment I've found a workaround but it will not work correctly as I expected, my radio input will remain selected also when a new question is rendered!

Comment: You can put any component as a slide, not only images.

Comment: I know but as I writed, I think it's not the best solution for a mobile quiz app ui

Comment: Then you should give a try to buttons with routes, I think.

Comment: In this case I'm not sure how to implement it because I don't have a survey id but the questions are loaded from the backend when the app is loaded and then after the user press a start button thay are displayed. At the moment I can think to create a Questions component put to display each question I need to pass the index of each question to the router?

Comment: Yes, you can have an array of questions objects in ```Questions``` component, the index of current question will be its id.

Comment: Or if you store your questions in Vuex store you don't have to create ```Questions``` component at all. How do you store these questions?

Comment: I'm using vuex at the moment. I've tried to use the router to test your suggestion but since I'm working on an android webview app it will not work as expected and the params will be not passed into the url !

Comment: That's bad. You should have mentioned all your restrictions in question.

Comment: I've opted for a standard `v-for` and a CSS based solution to achive my scope. The button solution or the route one was causing me some issue so wasn't at all reliables with android webView. Anyway thank you for the help :)