# Vuejs - Radio input remain checked when a new question is rendered in mobile app

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have implemented a tricky solution to [display some questions without using v-for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67600685/vuejs-implement-previous-next-buttons-to-display-surveys-questions/67602189#67602189). I need it to avoid that all the questions are rendered at the same time in a mobile android app, this will avoid scroll. The logics works fine but I've noticed that when the user select an answer and the next new question is rendered, the radio input to select the answer will be not resetted and the selected radio input will be equal to the previous choiced from the user. The problem will not occur if I use `v-for` to render the questions but as I wrote, this isn't what I want.

```html
<div class="container-fluid bg-light vh-100" v-if="isLoaded">
    <div class="row m-0">
    
      <div class="col-12 card shadow p-0 mt-5">
        <div class="card-header">
          <h6 class="fw-bold">{{ questions[n].question }}</h6>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
          <div class="form-check mb-3" v-for="(choice, index) in questions[n].choices" :key="index">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" :name="questions[n].questionIndex" :value="index" @change="checkAnswer(questions[n].questionIndex, index)" :disabled="answeredQuestions[n]">
            <small class="form-check-label" for="">{{ index }}) {{ choice }}</small>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="navbar bg-light fixed-bottom">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <small :class="score">{{ currentScore }}</small>
    </div>
  </div>
```

```js
export default {
  name: 'Quiz',
  data() {
    return {
      n: 0,
      answeredQuestions: [],
      currentScore: 0
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    front.on('questions', (data) => { 
      console.log(data) 
      this.$store.commit('quizQuestions', data);
      this.$store.commit('contentLoaded', true);
    });

    front.on('checkResponse', (response) => {
      console.log(response);
      if( response.answerCheck ){
        this.currentScore++; 
      }
      this.showNext(); 
    });
  },
  computed: {
    isLoaded() {
      return this.$store.getters.showLoader;
    },
    questions() {
      return this.$store.getters.quiz;
    },
    score() {
      return this.currentScore > 0 ? 'text-success' : 'text-muted';
    }
  },
  methods: {
    showPrevious() {
      if( this.n !== 0 ){
        this.n--
      }
    },
    showNext() {
      if( this.n < this.$store.getters.quiz.length ){
        this.n++
      }
    },
    checkAnswer(questionIndex, choice) {
      this.answeredQuestions.push(true);
      front.send('checkAnswer', {questionIndex: questionIndex, choice: choice});
    }
  }
}
```

I think that the problem is with the `name` attribute of the radio inputs but not sure of this. Any idea of how I can solve this?

Comment: do you have codepen on this? hard to try it out by just seeing the code

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try this. bind your questions[n].answer in your input value. Once you get a new question, if the answer haven't fill in before. It will auto become null.

```
 <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" :name="questions[n].questionIndex" :value="questions[n].answer" @change="checkAnswer(questions[n].questionIndex, index)" :disabled="answeredQuestions[n]">
```

Comment: I don't think this will work because `questions[n].answer` will provide the correct answer value for each radio input that can be choiced and this isn't a correct beahviour for a quiz app!

Comment: i meant binding the "submitAnswer" here, not the question's answer.

Comment: I need to create another variable to achive this, at the moment the most similar I have into the code is the `answeredQuestions[n]` array that will track if a question is alteady answered or not. But thie problem I think is with the `name` attribute because if I use a `v-for` loop and all the questions are rendered on the dom, the problem will not occur.

Comment: You don't need to create a new variable. Is another key in your 'question' object, if you want to track is the question have answered by the user, you can use filter function to check.

Comment: I don't have any key to check if an answer is already answered in my question object why you've supposed this?Anyway the point is that the problem is with the `name` attribute. using `value` and binding it to a variable or an object property will not solve the issue

Comment: Can you put it in codepen for easier debugging

Comment: Unfortunately I'm unable to create a JSfiddle or codepen of this. Anyway I've ended up with a CSS based solution that use the element position `relative` and `absolute` to avoid the scroll in my mobile app and the `display` property to hide questions until the current question index is the same of the `n` variable. I've also replaced the way to iterate the questions manually with a standrd `v-if` and seems solved. Thank you for the help

Comment: I created for you. check it out!
https://codesandbox.io/s/update-radio-btn-dpfjo